# possible reason of crash of following code?

Tags: c, pointers, crash, char

I tested the following code on two different compilers, it crashed on first but worked fine on second?

The code is

```
char *str="testing";
*str='b';
printf("%c",*str);
```

#### output : crashed on first compiler

#### `b` on second compiler

What may be the possible reason of crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the crash is that writing into a string literal's memory is undefined behavior. Your code `*str='b'` writes directly into the first `char` of memory allocated to the string literal. C allows compilers to place the content of literals into the memory area that is protected from writing. Writing anywhere in that region causes a segmentation fault.

Change the declaration to

```
char str[]="testing";
```

to avoid the error. If you declare `str` as a `char` array (as opposed to a `char` pointer) the compiler generates code to copy the content of `str` into writable memory, thus avoiding the error when you write to `str`.

Comment: Because this is not string literal.

Comment: @haccks : then what it is?

Comment: @kevingomes It is an array of characters. Please see the update to the answer.

Comment: how can we define string literal?

Comment: @kevingomes A string literal is a sequence of characters inside double-quotes. That's the only way of defining it. You can convert it to a `char` array, but you can also convert it to a non-writable pointer (in the sense that it's illegal to write that pointer, but the compiler will allow it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You are writing into a string literal, this has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Often (and as you see, on a system-dependent basis), string literals are put in read-only memory, and then trying to change them will cause a run-time error.

Comment: but I have declared as `char *` not `const char*`

Comment: Your pointer is of type `char *`, but it is nonetheless pointing to constant memory.  (The usual interpretation is that writing `char *` instead of `const char *` is the error.)